# Foundation for Apps in a theme directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, zurb-foundation, gulp, silverstripe

I'm trying to create a SilverStripe theme using Zurb's [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/) and I'm having trouble getting Foundation's template loading to work with the directory structure.

Normally Foundation's structured like this:

- (root)/    <-- site root, contains gulpfile.js etc
- (root)/client/   <-- contains raw files, scss etc
- (root)/build/    <-- client files get compiled to here by gulp.

What I'm trying to do is this:

- (root)/themes/devtheme/   <-- contains raw files, gulpfile, basically all of Foundation
- (root)/themes/livetheme/  <-- files get compiled to here

Basically:

a) Foundation is in a subdirectory but still accessed with a root URL (eg http://example.com/) because SilverStripe loads the templates from it's controller.

b) The compiled files are but in a sibling directory of Foundation rather than a child.

This mostly works by just specifying output directories in gulpfile.js like `.pipe(gulp.dest('../'+outputTheme))`.

The problem is loading page templates by AJAX. Front-router compiles a list of routes and the paths to their template files but it makes them relative (templates/mypage.html) it tries to fetch `example.com/templates/mypage.html` instead of `example.com/themes/livetheme/templates/mypage.html`.

SO

a) **Is there a way to specify a root or something in the client side JavaScript that gets added to the paths in foundationRoutes?**

b) **Failing that is there a way to get front-router to write full paths to routes.js?**  I've tried passing various values of root and dir to it but it gets passed through node's `path.relative()` which never gives them the result I'd expect.

Eg having this in gulpfile.js

```
    gulp.task('copy:templates', function() {
      return gulp.src('./templates/**/*.*')
        .pipe(router({
          path: '../livetheme/javascript/routes.js',
          root: '/templates/',
          dir: 'themes/livetheme'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../livetheme/templates'))
      ;
    });
```

results in this routes.js file:

```
var foundationRoutes = [{"name":"home","url":"/","path":"../../../templates/Layout/home.html"}];
```

When I really want the path to be "themes/livetheme/templates/Layout/home.html"

Sorry this is a bit of a mess, I'm not sure what information is relevant to the problem.